# odoo: Update parent field from one2many relation

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I have one model with 2 one2many relations (mat_gen and rh_gen). The first relation has a field named "qte", i want to update the second one when the "qte" changes with an onchange method.

```
@api.onchange('qte')
def onchange_qte(self):
    mat = self.browse(self._origin.id)
    if mat:
        mo = self.env["plg.ressource.rh"].browse(mat.ch.id)
        if mo:
            temp = []
            temp.append({
                'code': mo.code,
                'designation': mo.designation,
                'unite': mo.unite.id,
                'qte': self.qte,
                'aff_pr': self.aff_pr,
                'prixu': mo.prixu,
            })
```

Here i've to access the parent model to update the second relation like `self.parent.update({'rh_gen':temp})`
but obviously the parent variable does not exist.
How can i fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your child model simplified probably looks something likes this:

```
class child1(models.Model):
    _name = 'child1.model'
    parent = fields.Many2one('parent.model', 'Parent')
    qte = fields.Char('Qte')
    # ...
```

In your child1 `onchange` method, you can access the parent object and its fields through the corresponding `Many2one` field:

```
parent = self.parent
```

If you need to create a new child2 record, you can also do:

```
self.env['child2.model'].create({'parent': self.parent.id,
                                'qte': self.qte,
                                # ...
                                })
```